# Why is the style of my programmatically created button different?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-button, material-components-android

Starting with a new project in Android Studio with an empty Activity, I add a linear layout with a single button in `activity_main.xml`:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Demo01" />
</LinearLayout>
```

then in my `MainActivity`, I programmatically add a second button:

```kotlin
val buttonsLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.buttons)
val button = Button(this)
button.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
)
button.text = "Demo 01"
buttonsLayout.addView(button)
```

Finally when I run this app, I see this:

[image: buttons with different colors]

The first and second buttons seem to have different styles.

Why are they different? Furthermore, what's the correct way to programmatically create new views so that the programmatically created views have the same style as their xml layout counterparts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different because you are using a `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` theme.
With this theme the `Button` defined in the layout is [**replaced at runtime**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.3.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java) by a `MaterialButton`.

To have the same button you have to use:

```
    val buttonsLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.buttons)
    val button = MaterialButton(this)
    //...
    button.text = "Demo01"
    buttonsLayout.addView(button)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works for me! I do have a couple questions though. Is there a place I can read more about this behavior? I'm also curious if there's a mechanism to automatically choose the proper Button/view subclass. Maybe something like `theme.newButton(..)` that picks the correct Button class based on the current theme?

Comment: @math4tots in the base theme is defined `<item name="viewInflaterClass">com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater</item>`. This [class](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.3.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java) is called at runtime and replaces some widget.